# RavenDB query on property of Id struct

Tags: linq, ravendb

I am trying to locate documents in RavenDb based on one property of a custom ID struct:

```
struct UserId { 
    public int CompanyCode { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeCode { get; set; }
}

class User {
    public UserId Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeData { get; set; }
}

class UserIdConverter : ITypeConverter { 
    public bool CanConvertFrom(Type t) { return t == typeof(UserId); }
    public string ConvertFrom(string tag, object value, bool allowNull) { ... }
    public object ConvertTo(string value) { ... }
}
```

This query always gives no results:

```
public User[] GetUsersByCompanyCode(int companyCode) 
{
    var users = (from u in _session.Query<User>()
                 where u.Id.CompanyCode == companyCode
                 select u).ToArray();
    return users;
}
```

However, this version returns correct results:

```
public User[] GetUsersByCompanyCode(int companyCode) 
{
    var users = (from u in _session.Query<User>().ToArray()
                 where u.Id.CompanyCode == companyCode
                 select u).ToArray();
    return users;
}
```

What is the best way to achieve this without loading all the documents?

Comment: I can reproduce this but have no solution but rather a question: Does the Company Code really belong in the UserId struct? If you model it as a property on the User entity instead that query will be trivial.

Comment: @Jaynard, I can't change the UserId structure, but I could duplicate the CompanyCode into a field of the User document and query from there. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default RavenDB uses the `Id` property as the identity of the document, and complex types are not supported (as far as I know). I recommend reading [Working with document identifiers](http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/client-api/document-identifiers/working-with-document-ids).

In general you can change the name of the identity property in [`Conventions.FindIdentityProperty`](http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/client-api/configuration/conventions/identifier-generation/global), but I recommend to change the name of the `UserId` property and have an additional property `Id` of type `string`:

```
class User {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public UserId UserId { get; set; }
    public string SomeData { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Complex types can be used as Id fields when used with an ITypeConverter. The converter basically transforms the complex type to/from a string. But it seems like they cannot be used in queries.

Comment: After some further digging I realize the code is doing effectively as you suggest, by using a  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "UserId")] attribute on the Id property.  This causes the string based Id to be used as the key, and the full object to be available in Raven queries as "UserId".  So now my problem boils down to how to query against properties that have been re-mapped like this.